Admin Login issues with Landscape self hosted server with Azure SSO
Our organisation has opted to use Landscape self hosted server because of its "bring your own sso" feature. We plan to use it with ubuntu pro servers.
But We have a lot of issue making sso work.
I understand that administrators need to accept invites sent to them by email, but we are having some weird incosistant result in the authorisation part of the process:

For some of our users, the authentication part fails completely

For other, authentication work, but they get an error message saying that "the invitation is intended for a different recipient"

For other yet they get the same error message as above, but they still are able to go through and are added to the list of active administrator

And for the rest everything seems to be working.


Short of reading the code, I haven't found any information on what is used by the authentication/authorisation process.
The only thing that seems to consistantly work is that all user receive their bearer token from Azure, and from Azure point of view, authentication is successfull.
So I am guessing the landscape server app makes the determination based on the user info it receives from azure. We are wondering what is used in the logic to make that determination.
